# Removable and non-removable discontinuity in one function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is is possible to have a function with a removable and nonremovable discontinuity?

Is there a paper or site that I can see how this is possible or understand this better?

Comment: Do you mean a single point that is both removable and non-removable simultaneously, or two points of discontinuity, one which is removable and the other which is not? The former is impossible and the latter is possible.

Comment: @SE318 I think any rational person would rule out the first possibility based simply on nomenclature. The wording of the question also does not at all suggest that that is what the OP means.

Comment: An example is $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$. $1$ is a removable discontinuity, $2$ is a non-removable one.

Comment: @MattSamuel the fact that the OP said "a removable and nonremovable discontinuity", if read strictly would be a single point that is both since "a" and "discontinuity" are singular.

Comment: Just to mention a curious example in the vicinity of this question:  $f\colon\mathbb Q\to \mathbb R$, $\frac ab\mapsto\frac1b$ is not continuous anywhere in its domain, but all points in $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ are removable discontinuities.

Comment: @MattSamuel also, referral to "nomenclature" is quite possibly the least mathematical thing I have seen on this site. I suppose you claim that a set is closed if it isn't open and that no set can be both open and closed by nomenclature?

Comment: @SE318: That argument would carry some force is if "closed" was actually called "nonopen", but it isn't, exactly because it is _not_ the same as "not open". Can you point to any context in which where "X" and "non-X" denote properties that are _not_ mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x-2)}$$ is not defined for $x=1$ and $x=2$.

However, the limit for $x\rightarrow 1$ exists.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} f(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 1} \frac{1}{x-2}=-1$$

Denominator and numerator tend to $0$. This does not imply that the
limit exists, but it is the case in this example. Setting
$f(1)=-1$, we can remove the singularity at $x=1$.

The limit for $x\rightarrow 2$ does not exist.

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} f(x)=\pm \infty$$

depending on the way, x approaches to $2$.  The reason is, that the 
numerator remains positive and the denominator tends to $0$, if
$x$ tends to $2$. The singularity cannot be removed, no matter which
value we choose for $f(2)$.

Comment: So, the phenomen of removable and non-removable singularities does not only appear for piecewise defined functions , but also appears for rational functions.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could have
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when }x<0 \\
1 & \text{when }x=0 \\
0 & \text{when }0<x<1 \\
1 & \text{when }1\le x \end{cases} $$
which has a removable discontinuity at $0$ and a nonremovable one at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0, &  x = 0 \\ 
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}, & 0<x<1 \\
0, &x \geq 1 \\
\end{cases}.$$

The discontinuity at $0$ is removable since the limit of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ as $x$ goes to $0$ is 1. The discontinuity at $1$ is not removable.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
1/x, &  x < 1 \\ 
0, & x = 1 \\
x, &x > 1 \\
\end{cases}.$$

Then $f$ has an non removable discontinuity at $x = 0$ (vertical asymptote), and a removable discontinuity at $x = 1$.

Comment: It does not have a discontinuity at $x=0$ unless you define it there, which you don't seem to have done.

Comment: Sorry, typo, see now.